# How to setup a new domain using WHM and Register.com

Tags: dns, hosting, server, whm

I'am unable to make my website work after a server changing. Whether I access http://IP/~user/ or www.mydomain.com it just doesn't work. I am going mad.

Using the IP I get a Server not Found error (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in Chrome); using the domain I get this:
[image]

What I did:

**WHM**

Hostname: `localhost.mydomain.com`

Primary resolver: `103.254.153.22`  (<--[LeaseWeb Singapore DNS Server](https://kb.leaseweb.com/display/KB/Cheat+Sheet))

Secondary resolver: `127.0.0.1`

Nameserver and                                Resolved IP:

```
ns1.mydomain.com      216.21.224.199  (<--Register.com IP)
ns2.mydomain.com      216.21.224.199  (<--Register.com IP)
```

I created a user called `user123`.

**Register.com**

I already had a domain in a previous IP. 
So I only changed the A records to my new IP.
I let these nameservers:

```
dns193.a.register.com.   ['216.21.231.193']   
dns193.b.register.com.   ['216.21.232.193']   
dns226.c.register.com.   ['216.21.235.226']   
dns249.d.register.com.   ['216.21.236.249']
```

**Server**:

I sent all my PHP code to `/home/user123/public_html`.
I installed all the packages and extensions needed.

If there is any important information missing, let me know. I am a newbie in this matter, so please be patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error using the domain was different because my Register.com hadn't done the transition to the new IP yet.

To access my server meanwhile, instead of using the IP I used http://Hostname/~user/ (in my case http://localhost.mydomain.com/~user123/) and it worked.

PS: In fact there were other problems, like Apache using a incorrect DirectoryRoot, but that's another story...

Comment: you can check for dns error here: https://www.whoisextractor.in/dns-health-checkup/ and if every thing is fine then wait for propagation, after that site will be accessible.